# Replicate MATLAB's FFT in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Sorry for maybe phrasing the question imprecisely, but I'm quite new both to Simulink and Stack.

I'm trying to process a speech signal in simulink, as I did in Matlab, and I have a problem with the output. In Matlab, FFT looks like this:

[image: matlab].

Now, when I feed my simulink model (buffer, windowing matlab function, fft matlab function) with this signal, depending on how long I run the simulation, an output like this:

[image: simulink]

Which I find hard to relate to what I get in Matlab.
What should I do in order to get the exact same output in Simulink as in Matlab?

**Edit:**

My Simulink model looks lie this:

[image]
While Function1 is:

```
'function y = window(u)  
coder.extrinsic('windowing');  
y=zeros(2048,1);  
y = windowing(u); %multiplying the signal by the same-length Hamming window  
end'
```

And Function2 is:

```
'function y = fft1(u)  
coder.extrinsic('abs', 'fft', 'melbankm', 'frq2mel', 'mel2frq');  
y=zeros(2048,1);  
y = abs(fft(u,2048));  
end'
```

And the input signal is:

Comment: From the rules: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*. In your case, it would be good to have a screenshot of the key bit of your model, what your data looks like, how you've tried to make the MATLAB and Simulink outputs the same, etc.

Comment: The first plot is a spectrum (with frequency on the x-axis).  The second is a time series plot (with time on the x-axis).  So they are never going to be the same.  The easiest way to get a spectrum in Simulink is to use the [Spectrum Analyser](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/spectrumanalyzer.html) block, but that's in the DSP Blockset.  But even then, in MATLAB you have a static image of the spectrum at one time point.  In SImulink the spectrum will update at each time step (based on the window of data being being analyzed at that time).

Comment: Spectrum Analyzer will not do the trick, because I need the signal for further processing. In order to handle bigger chunks of static image of spectrum I'm using buffer blocks.

Comment: If you need the spectrum and have the DSP Blockset then just use one of the flavors of FFT blocks in the blockset.

Comment: I would do that if it was just about the FFT. The point is I'm processing the signal further with other matlab functions (mel filter bank, DCT), and there I have similar problems, so I figured the FFT example will be simpler, and I could apply a similar solution for next steps.